# `std::alloc::Allocator` is not satisfied

Tags: rust

I have an enum that has two variants, right, and left, these two variants contain a `Vec<Token, Expr>`. Here are their definitions:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Token {
    ...
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Expr {
    Var(Token, Token),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Side {
    Left(Vec<Token, Expr>),
    Right(Vec<Token, Expr>),
}
```

I want each variant of side to contain any combination of `Token` or `Expr`. This can be in any order. When I run this, I get an error saying that `std::alloc::Allocator` is not satisfied for `Expr`. Why is `Allocator` not satisfied for `Expr` but for `Token`? Also, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you expect `Vec<Token, Expr>` to mean?

Comment: I expect `Vec<Token, Expr>` to be a vector where there could be any combination of the two. For example, `vec![Expr::..., Token::..., Token::..., Expr::...]` or `vec![Token::..., Expr::..., Expr::..., Token::...]`. Any combination of the two

Comment: For that you'd want another enum, something like `enum TokenOrExpr { Token(Token), Expr(Expr) }` and then `Vec<TokenOrExpr>`. Only the first type parameter for `Vec` indicates the items stored, the second one is optional and used to indicate the allocator used to manage the underlying memory.